# Changing the class of an element in html using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently trying to change the class of a set of images when I press a button on my keyboard (<kbd>a</kbd>). I have written the following code:

```
    <div id="images" class="img"/>
 <img src="spiderman.png" alt=""/>
 <img src="superman.png" alt="" height="25%" width="25%"/>
 <img src="batman.png" alt="" />
</div>

<Script type="text/javascript">
    function keyDown(event) {
      if (event.keyCode == 65) {
        var canvas = document.getElementById('images');
        canvas.innerHTML = '<img class="img2" />'
      }
    }
    function keyUp(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 65) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('images');
    canvas.innerHTML = '<img class="img" />';
  }
}
</script>
```

css

```
  .img {
  position: absolute;  
  right: 15%; 
  top: 30%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
.img2 {
box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #fff;
  position: absolute;  
  right: 15%; 
  top: 30%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

I am very new to both html and JavaScript so have no idea why this isn't working or even if I have used JavaScript correctly within my html, is what I am trying to achieve even possible? A point in the right direction would be helpful :)

Comment: Is `#images` actually a `canvas` element? as that is not how you load images into a `canvas`. Currently those `img` tags have no `src` attribute, and so wont load an image. Is there a reason you're dynamically inserting the `img` tag rather than having it in the DOM already?

Comment: is this what you're trying to do? toggle the box-shadow when you press "a"? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qrVjMO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you are not replacing the element class. You are replacing the image itself. If you want to change the clas use this:

```
document.getElementById("MyElement").className = "MyOtherClass"
```

So it's going to be something like:

```js
 (function() {

   function keyDown(event) {
     if (event.keyCode == 65) {
       if (document.getElementsByClassName("img").length > 0) {
         document.getElementsByClassName("img")[0].className = "img2"
       } else {
         document.getElementsByClassName("img2")[0].className = "img"
       }
     }
   }

   document.addEventListener('keydown', keyDown);
 })();
```

```css
.img {
  width: 100px
}

.img2 {
  width: 400px
}
```

```html
<img class="img" src="http://www.axpe-blogs.com/wp-content/uploads/stackoverflow_logo.jpg" />
```